# How can I modify an instruction in a process? Linux & ARMv7

Tags: linux, permissions, arm

I tried to modify the first instruction of a function called **g**, but got a segment fault on the second statement in the following snippet

```
int a = *(int*)g;
*(int*)g=0;  // segment fault!
*(int*)g=a;
```

Was this segment fault due to the **no-write** permission in the page table entry for the page where the instruction I wanted to modify was located ?

I did so because I wanted to see if I could patch a function with some bugs, while keeping the process running, like this:

1) A process with function **g** is running, and that **g** has been found to have some bugs. So write a new function called **patch_g**, which has no bugs.

2) Compile the new function into **patch.so**

3) **dlopen** & **dlsym** the .so file. Get the address of **patch_g**.

4)  Suspend the running process

5) Use some code (somewhat similar to the second statement of the snippet above) to change the first instruction of **g** into `jump patch_g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's do an experiment.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*functionPtr)(int,int);

int addInt(int n, int m) {
        return n+m;
}


int main()
{
    functionPtr = &addInt;
    printf("%p\n", functionPtr);
    while(1){};
    *(int *) functionPtr = 0x0;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile

```
$ gcc -o ./main.c main
```

Launch this app in first console.

```
$ ./main 
0x40052d
```

In second console

```
$ cat /proc/`pidof main`/maps
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6345711                            /tmp/main
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 6345711                            /tmp/main
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 6345711                            /tmp/main
```

...

This **r-xp** means that when kernel loaded this binary, it has mapped text section into private virtual mapping with read and execute permissions, but without write permissions. I think this is done because of security reasons.

So appropriate vma_area in kernel marked as non writable, what leads to unhandled userspace page fault i.e. segfault is occured.

Now let'us add mprotect call to appropriate place

```
 17         if (mprotect((void *)0x00400000, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC)) {
 18                 printf("error\n");
 19                 return -1;
 20         }
```

You will notice that this will help your with your run-time patching idea.

```
00400000-00401000 rwxp 00000000 08:01 6345711                            /tmp/main
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 6345711                            /tmp/main
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 6345711                            /tmp/main
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Alex. Good to know /proc/pid/maps and mprotect.